# Debouncing onChange event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my SuggestBox component I found that sometimes event.target.value is becoming undefined sometimes and I couldn't find how to fix that.

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

let debounce = require('lodash.debounce');
let uniqueKey = 0;
let jqxhr = {
    abort: () => {
    }
};

export default class SuggestBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.doneTyping = debounce(this.doneTyping.bind(this), this.props.delay);
        this.state = {
            hidden: true,
            data: []
        }
    }

    render() {
        const hidden = this.state.hidden ? {display: 'none'} : {display: 'block'};

        return (
            <div className="ReactSuggestion-Wrapper">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, event)}
                    onFocus={this.showSuggestBox.bind(this, event)}
                    onBlur={this.hideSuggestBox.bind(this, event)}
                />
                <div style={hidden} className="ReactSuggestion-SuggestionBox">
                    {this.state.data.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <ul key={uniqueKey++} className="ReactSuggestion-SuggestionList">
                                <li className="ReactSuggestion-SuggestionHeader">
                                    <p>
                                        {item.header.title}
                                    </p>
                                </li>
                                {item.data.map((data, dataKey) => {
                                    return (
                                        <li key={dataKey} className="ReactSuggestion-SuggestionItems">
                                            <a className="ReactSuggestion-Data">
                                                <div className="ReactSuggestion-Data__Thumbnail">
                                                    <img src={data.image} className="ReactSuggestion-Data__ThumbnailImage"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="ReactSuggestion-Data__Details">
                                                    <p className="ReactSuggestion-Data__DetailsPrimary">
                                                        {data.primary}
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p className="ReactSuggestipn-Data__DetailsSecondary">
                                                        {data.secondary}
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </ul>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    showSuggestBox(event) {
        if (event.target.value == '') {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.state.oldValue == event.target.value) {
            this.setState({
                hidden: false
            })
        }
    }

    hideSuggestBox(event) {
        this.setState({
            hidden: true,
            oldValue: this.state.value
        })
    }

    onChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        })
        this.doneTyping()
    }

    doneTyping() {
        const self = this;
        jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            data: {q: this.state.value},
            type: this.props.method,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: relay => {
                let empty = false;
                relay.forEach(item => {
                    empty = item.data.length > 0 ? false : true;
                })
                if (empty)
                    return false;

                self.setState({
                    data: relay,
                    hidden: false
                })
            }
        })
    }
}

SuggestBox.propTypes = {
    url: React.PropTypes.string,
    method: React.PropTypes.string,
    delay: React.PropTypes.number
}
```

As you can see in my constructor has the

```
this.doneTyping = debounce(this.doneTyping.bind(this), this.props.delay);
```

code which is preventing event pooling in react so react obeys the debounce, but in my ajax request somehow my event.target.value or this.state.value is becomes undefined and I can't send ajax requests. However sometimes it can fixes itself and sending values.

How to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

You're binding [window.event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) as the first argument of your event handlers. Change `fn.bind(this, event)` to  `fn.bind(this)` here:

```
<input
    type="text"
    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, event)}
    onFocus={this.showSuggestBox.bind(this, event)}
    onBlur={this.hideSuggestBox.bind(this, event)}
/>
```

#### Explanation

When you do `fn.bind(this, arg1, arg2)`, you're correctly binding the `this` context, but you're also specifying extra arguments that will be prepended to your argument list when the function is called.

More specifically, if you do `showSuggestionBox.bind(this)`, then `this` will be your `SuggestionBox` instance, and your arguments will look like:

```
showSuggestionBox(reactEvent)
```

But if you do `showSuggestionBox.bind(this, event)` (like you have above) then it will be like your function is called like this:

```
showSuggestionBox(window.event, reactEvent)
```

So the React event you care about is being replaced by `window.event`.
I'm just guessing, but I don't think that React guarantees that your `onEvent` callbacks will be called in a way that matches the `window.event` lifecycle.
So you could consider `event === undefined` to be the normal code path, and when you get a value you're just getting lucky with the timing.

#### References

[1] [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)